# A verb for giving motivation for a topic

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good word for giving motivation to a topic and that can be used in the following manner:

> Our research on the cultural history of industrial adhesives is [blank] by the entire lack of scientific literature on that topic.

or

> The study of spontaneous wood combustion is [blank] by the traditional use of wooden furniture.

Note that I am looking for a word that can be used in passive in the above examples.

It seems that some people would use 'motivated' in the above examples, but to my understanding, this can only be used as in 'to motivate people'.

Comment: No, *motivated* isn't restricted to humans (hint: *motivate*,  *motor*, and *move* share an etymology). A dictionary would have cleared up any fears you had, before asking, and a thesaurus will provide you alternatives words to *motivate* if you have any remaining.

Comment: In fact, I did consult a dictionary. The examples were inconclusive.

Comment: Include that information in your question (use the [edit]) link. Tell us what dictionary you used, what you found in it, and why those findings were unsatisfactory or inconclusive.

Comment: People are the ones being motivated!  Research and Study are being motivated, both human activities.

Comment: You can't  "Motivate technology to advance", but you can "Motivate researchers to advance technology".  "The research on the technology  is motivated by the engineers' love for knowledge'

Comment: @Tom22 You can and often do *motivate a question*. This is a very common turn of phrase in academia.

Comment: @DanBron ... well a question is a human thing isn't it? (similar to study, inquiry ,research etc)  I imagine machines with Artificial Intelligence could be motivated to do any applicable verb,  as can dogs. That being said,  I'm not trying to make a firm categorical rule that the OP suggests, but I was pointing out that the examples he gave did fit his own rule.

Comment: @Tom22 If we stretch a metaphor far enough, we can say anything is a "person thing". But no, physicists speak of *motive forces*, mechanical engineers speak of engines as *motivations*, and so on. In general, anything which can be set into motion, human, animal, or inanimate, is capable of being *motivated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> Our research on the cultural history of industrial adhesives is **driven** by the entire lack of scientific literature on that topic.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/driven), this usage most fits the second definition of driven:

> 1 :  having a compulsive or urgent quality
>
> 2 :  propelled or motivated by something —used in combination <results-driven>

Answer (score 1):

You could use **occasion** here, though there is perhaps too much *depersonalisation* with this one: too much *cause* and too little *prompt*.

> **occasion** verb [ T ]  formal ​
>
> to cause something:
>
> Her refusal occasioned a lot of trouble.
>
> [ + two objects ] The case occasioned the authorities a lot of worry /
>   The authorities were occasioned a lot of worry by the case.

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occasion)]

Answer (score 1):

**prompted** would fit your usage

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prompted?s=t):

> 5. to move or induce to action:
>      *What prompted you to say that?*
> 6. to occasion or incite; inspire:
>      *What prompted his resignation?*

[OxfordDictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prompt):

> 1.1 (prompt someone to/to do something) Cause someone to take a course of action:
>   *curiosity prompted him to look inside*

Answer (score 1):

Consider **stirred up**.

> [Stir up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stir+up) definition: provide the needed stimulus for; instigate.
>
> Example: *Hopefully the creativity stirred up by the speakers will provide the impetus for the students to be innovative and productive*.

Answer (score 1):

A common word for this is ***inspire***.

> Our research on the cultural history of industrial adhesives is
>   ***inspired*** by the entire lack of scientific literature on that topic.
>
> The study of spontaneous wood combustion is ***inspired*** by the
>   traditional use of wooden furniture.

ODO:

> **[inspire](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inspire)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **1.3** Give rise to
>
> ‘For instance, seeing O'Toole and Burton spar in the pro-cleric film
>   Beckett helped ***inspire*** my studies of medieval history.’
>
> **Synonyms**:   give rise to, lead to, result in, bring about, cause, be the cause of, prompt, produce, spawn, engender

M-W:

> **[inspire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspire)**
>   [inspired; inspiring]
>   *transitive verb*
>
> **5 a** :  bring about, occasion : the book was inspired by his travels in the Far East